# Ruby, pass/return a counter in a recursive code block

Tags: ruby, counter

How would I pass an index through a series of code blocks?

```
# i'm not sure how to set this up
def call(index=0, &block)    # index here is likely not needed
    yield (index+1) # or block.call(index)
end

call{call{call{}}}
```

should give a total count (3) and the count at each call
preferably without having to explicitly use call { |i|  call{ |i|   } }

Comment: Can you explain why you are trying to do this? Not obvious from your example. DSL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this variant:

```
def call(index = 0)
  if block_given? and (res = yield(index + 1)) != nil
    res + 1
  else
    index + 1
  end
end
```

Comment: +1. All the `index` parameter part can be removed, though. `def call ; (block_given? && res = yield) ? res + 1 : 1 ; end`

Comment: thank you! I'm still trying to understand this.  If i wanted to perform an action/call method or return a concatenation of strings how would it be possible by this way?

Comment: Sure, the key moment - `res + 1`, so if you want to concatenate strings you can do `res + ' bar'` .